# imagemagick not responding

Tags: imagemagick, exec, debian

After installing of imageMagick on a Debian Machine (debian_version 6.0.2)

Running this command:

```
/usr/bin/convert -scale "90x>" -quality 80 -strip "/right/path/source.jpg" "/right/path/destination.jpg"
```

doesn't save the destination image in */right/path/*
and returns no errors.

"convert" is found into */usr/bin/* so that's where the command should be launched from...but nothing happens...

permissions are set "775" for each folders i'm saving the file in.

writing:

```
echo exec("whoami");
```

works and returns "www-data" wich has any kind of permissions

Any clue why/what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: i found out was a permission problem.

Comment: You should put this into an answer for the posterior world to find more easily. Also, you can then even upvote and accept your own answer for the goods of your reputation score  :-)